# Creating window class for Dialog

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, wndproc

I create a window class with static window proc for dialog window and have an error executed when window is creating: access denied when writing location "0x00000000"

```
// ... Creating window
_hWnd = CreateDialogParam(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), NULL, WndProc, (LPARAM)this);
```

And window proc function:

```
static INT_PTR CALLBACK MainWindow::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MainWindow * wnd = NULL;

    if(message == WM_NCCREATE) {

         wnd = reinterpret_cast<MainWindow *>(((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams);
         ::SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<long>(wnd));
         wnd->_hWnd = hWnd;

    } else
         wnd = reinterpret_cast<MainWindow *>(::GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dialog's "first message" is [`WM_INITDIALOG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than `WM_NCCREATE`. The user data param is passed directly as the `lParam` value (rather than via a `LPCREATESTRUCT` pointed to by `lParam`).